# How to get high resolution photos from Facebook news feeds in iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an iPad application having functionality of fetching newsfeed from Facebook.but i am not able to get a High resolution newsfeed picture like Facebook iPad application. I have follow Facebook developer site but unable to get information related to this. Please suggest.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your App, modify your API call to include the `full_picture` field to get larger images where possible. E.g.:

```
/me/feed?fields=id,name,full_picture,story,message,picture
```

The downside is that you'll need to include the names of all the fields you need from the API. My example above only includes a subset of the fields that Facebook provides.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got the full_picture url in api.but when i opened link in the browser it is not opening a image while picture url is opening. for example: "full_picture":"https:\/\/fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net\/safe_image.php?d=AQBo4TQMnk-HML9I&url=https\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Ffbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net\u00252Fhphotos-ak-xfp1\u00252Fv\u00252Ft1.0-9\u00252Fs130x130\u00252F10690039_703280993088401_71827564448452497_n.jpg\u00253Foh\u00253D557a41912e49814f1224d735a9eaaa45\u002526oe\u00253D54C60CC4\u002526__gda__\u00253D1421203025_488c77ec8d4d3728e910823627dd0912",

Comment: and "picture":"https:\/\/fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xfp1\/v\/t1.0-9\/s130x130\/10690039_703280993088401_71827564448452497_n.jpg?oh=557a41912e49814f1224d735a9eaaa45&oe=54C60CC4&__gda__=1421203025_488c77ec8d4d3728e910823627dd0912",

Comment: Thanks. It is working in application. but full_picture not returning the large picture. only some picture return as a large otherwise most of picture return smaller.

Comment: I've noticed that too, but this is the correct way to get larger images. It could be a bug with the API.

Comment: is ' fields ' is the object_id ?

Comment: Yes, object_id 'fields' is also available.